# Volume of Sliced Parallelpiped - Triple Integrals (HW Problem)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to use a triple integral to compute the volume of a parallelepiped, which is basically a parallelogram in 3-d. The question goes as follows:

Use a triple integral to compute the volume of the following region. The larger of two solids formed when the parallelepiped (slanted box) with vertices $(0,0,0), (2,0,0), (0,2,0), (2,2,0), (0,1,1), (2,1,1), (0,3,1), (2,3,1)$ is sliced by the plane $y=2$.

Obviously, the quantity to be integrated is just $1 dzdydx$ but I am unsure of what to put for the integrand. I guess the bounds for x would be 0 and 2 and the z is bounded by z=3 and z=0, and y is bounded by the line y=2 and the point $(0,0,0)$ right?

Would the integral then be $\int_0^2 {\int_0^2 {\int_0^3 {1dzdydx}}}$ ? But it can't be... that would be the volume of a rectangular prism...and it seems to me that the shape is that of a trapezoidal prism.

These are just my thoughts so far, sorry if it seemed a bit scattered and random. By the way, this problem comes from the section titled *Triple Integrals in Rectangular Coordinates.*

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do the bounds on your triple integrals mean? For instance: For your inner-most integral, you have  $\int_{0}^{3} 1 dz$. This would mean that regardless of your values of $x$ and $y$, your $z$ is allowed to range from $0$ to $3$. In which case there are a couple problems already:

1st- in your problem, $z$ is always between zero and one. 

2nd- Your upper limit on $z$ when $y$ is close to zero is smaller than it is when $y$ is greater than $1$.